# Problem with "Display over other apps" permission on some MIUI versions

Tags: permissions, overlay, miui, system-alert-window

I am Android developer. And now I test my "anti-spam caller" application.
In case if application detects that there is incoming call from spammer it shows warning alert window.

For showing this window application requires "Display over other apps" permission.
The Application requests permission when opening (in case if permission not granted).

Regularly apllication sends analytics in firebase about state of permissions.

In firebase analytics I see that on specific Xiaomi devices with specific Android and MIUI version there is strange behaviour of "Display over other apps" permission status. To get the "Display over other apps" permission status Settings.candDrawOverlays() method is used.

"Display over other apps" automatically disables and enables every day without interacting with users (I suppose).
It happens for different users but for the same device models and OS versions.

Devices: Redmi Note 8T (MIUI: V12.5.1.0.RCXRUXM), Mi 9 Lite (MIUI: V12.5.2.0.RFCMIXM), Redmi Note 8 (MIUI: V12.5.2.0.RCOMIXM), Redmi Note 8 Pro (MIUI: V12.5.3.0.RGGRUXM), Mi 9 SE  (MIUI: V12.5.1.0.RFBMIXM), Mi 9T Pro (MIUI: V12.5.2.0.RFKMIXM)
Android version: 11

Questions are:

- What users behaviour can lead to automatic change of status of "Display over other apps" permission?
- It seems that there is problem of MIUI OS. Could you tell me how I can contact the developers of MIUI to ask questions?